# Issue in connecting to SQL DB

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have SQL Express on my machine. I asked the System  Admin to attach a DB for me(viz, **ACC_DB**). I opened my SQL Express and tried to connect to that DB, I couldn't connect. Then someone suggested I open it with **Priviledge guards**. I tried and was able to connect.

One of my Dot Net Applications uses this DB, but with current DB settings, the application is unable to connect to the DB.

Can I make appropriate modifications to my connection string so that it connects with Priviledge Guards automatically? Or any other way through which I can connect to the Db from the Dot Net app.

Comment: Any reason you can't just create a sql user for the application to connect with appropriate database permissions?

Comment: The user is added. Still unable to connect unless trying with Priveledge guards.

Comment: So the database is local but you can't connect, unless you use this third party software?

Comment: Maybe that Priviledge guard software is blocking your access.